# Are there performance differences between Intuos2 vs newer non-Cintiq Tablet?

Tags: drawing-tablet, hardware, hardware-recommendation

I have an Intuos2 that has been a nice, solid, tablet for years now and, as far as I know, I'm happy with it. Now, I say "as far as I know" because I've not had the opportunity to try anything new.

I'm looking to ramp up the amount of work I do which would require a tablet and am wondering if I am crippling myself by using such an old tablet. Like I said, it seems to work just fine. Smooth lines, keeps up with fast gestures, etc. However, I am clueless as to what the technical differences are between something so old and the most current tablets.

QUESTION: What are the technical differences between an Intuos2 and the most recent (non-Cintiq) tablets? I don't mean physical differences like lighter weight materials, wireless capabilities, sizes. I mean any difference in performance when stylus meets the tablet and begins to transmit data. Basically, why should I consider upgrading?

Tablet would be used mostly with Photoshop, Illustrator, and Manga Studio.

Answer (score 0):

The first primary difference is Pressure Sensitivity; the Intuos2 should have 1024 levels, while new alternative tablets have much more pressure, with 2048 levels.

Also higher resolutions; Intuos2 has 2,540 lpi of resolution, and comparable non wacom tablets today have 5080 lpi, or lines per inch. Third difference is drivers- with most non-wacom tablets, at the level I am talking about are much cheaper than the newer Wacom lines, but many people have to struggle with drivers. I am planning on buying a new non-wacom tablet myself, and the one I am considering is the Huion H610. You have to look for reviews on non-wacom tablets to be sure that you can get it to work on your OS.

I was considering for example, the Huion W58, which has wireless capality, however I couldn't find anyone who said that it could work on OSX 10, and it's driver process is more difficult. One thing that most people have an issue with with the drivers is plugging in their tablet before they install the drivers, or for OSX users, 3rd party plugins for other mouse controls. I suggest looking at reviews by this guy, as he does a lot on alternative tablets;http://frenden.com/post/60704895108/huion-h610-k58-and-w58-tablet-review-round-up

I only have experience with using a friend's cintiq and researching Huion; also this photo explains LPI more visually, but with cintaq and intuos-: https://cdn.tutsplus.com/psd/uploads/legacy/psdtutsarticles/article_alternatives_wacom_tablets/cintiq-test.jpg

I'm sorry I don't have the knowledge to answer your question better, but I tried my best, I hope it helps! I've heard some non-wacom tablets can have different pen smoothness as well, and since you have one already that works fine, you should decide based on the level of pen smoothness that you prefer for your work. Good luck!

Comment: Its a bit questionable if you need those numbers. Sure the system has a bigger resolution, however what is the [accuracy and precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision)? These are far more important factors than resolution in terms of usability. You can have a lot of resolution if its all noise. Then there's the how much accuracy can you actually benefit from. These are typically used by sales  because they are easy to say but affects very little.  On that subject however i have been really disappointed with Wacom drivers lately. So i see no reason not to test other drivers